# I need fast recording software for gaming specifically for minecraft

Tags: video, minecraft

I've tried recordmydesktop but it makes my computer lag. Kazam is kind of slow after encoding and there aren't enough options. And istanbul is for beginners. Vokoscreen I've used the most it works pretty well but I need an upgrade. VLC media player isn't a screen recorder and creates lag. Tibesti has the slowest fps for me. Simplescreenrecorder is over rated for gaming. Recorditnow it's recordmydesktop and ffmpeg (i've never tried ffmpeg). Xvidcap I used for a while but not anymore very basic though. GLC I never could use that software shift + f8 didn't record. Please help. :)

Comment: Which version of ubuntu do you use?
Why do you need an upgrade for vokoscreen? Problems?

Comment: 12.04 ubuntu. And for some reason vokoscreen start slowing down my  fps (it didn't before). I only record minecraft for now. I could use a better screen recorder with higher fps